# Error Code 13 from Jenkins when i load code from RTC with LSCM command Load from Jenkins using RTC

Tags: jenkins, rational-team-concert

Coming to the short description of the problem that we are facing, We are using the Batch command to integrate the RTC with Jenkins and using the load command as shown below.  It is failing with Exit code 13 and we are not getting any further information about the error, The same command when I run with command prompt it works fine. Need your help regarding the same.

```
lscm load -r http://ServerRepo  --all "workspace" --include-root  --force  
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
```

ERROR: script returned exit code 13
Finished: FAILURE

I have tried using the same command with CLI and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error, what I found was there was a mismatch in the parent pom.xml file. Jenkins typically does a good job updating these and configuring them automatically; sometimes, however, Jenkins fails to do this and attempts to build the same file of 2 different versions and fails. Check out your parent pom.xml file and make sure all the versions are correct.